# Check If a String Is Present and Its Position

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Sorry, a bit new to php. Have tried all I know, but failed and seeking expert help.

I have a string similar to this..
`/%mydocs%/%myfolder%/%date%/%filename%.html`

Basically the `%vars%` represents different strings and seperated by `/`, like a URL.

I need to find %date% (or any given variable) if it's present and it's position in the string, like it's at position 3 in the example above.

I tried this,

```
$date = preg_match( '%date%', '/%mydocs%/%myfolder%/%date%/%filename%.html');
```

But it's neither returning anything nor the position.

Any help, even some heads up to play with, will be appriciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using [preg_split](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php):

```
$var = '%date%';
$str = '/%mydocs%/%myfolder%/%date%/%filename%.html';
$list = preg_split('#/#', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
for($i=0; $i<count($list); $i++) {
    if ($list[$i] == $var) {
        echo "Found $var at position ",$i+1,"\n";
    }
}
```

**output:**

```
Found %date% at position 3
```

Comment: Thanks, but whenever I replace it with my vars and strings, it always returns 1. Here is my [code snippet](http://pastebin.com/Aj4PBskb). Please help.

Comment: @Abhik: change the affectation of `$reply` to `$reply = "Found $ppostname at position ". ($i+1) ."\n";`. Note the parenthesis arround `($i+1)`;

Comment: Hi again, I am facing a little issue. Whenever I am trying to get the position of a second variable, it returns nothing. Can you please help me? Here is the original code I am using. http://pastebin.com/jQuKtgsz

Answer (score 2):

### [strpos](http://pk1.php.net/strpos)

```
<?php
$mystring = '/%mydocs%/%myfolder%/%date%/%filename%.html';
$findme   = '%date%';
$pos = strpos($mystring, $findme);
if ($pos === false) {
    echo "The string '$findme' was not found in the string '$mystring'";
} else {
    echo "The string '$findme' was found in the string '$mystring'";
    echo " and exists at position $pos";
}
?>
```

**Result:**

`The string '%date%' was found in the string '/%mydocs%/%myfolder%/%date%/%filename%.html' and exists at position 21`

Comment: Thanks, this almost is what I need. However, when I tried your method, it returns the position at 21 (in your example too). But I need to get the position separated by `/`. Like I said it need to return 3, in my question. Shouldn't I explode or split or something before I do the `strpos`?

Answer (score 0):

preg_match returns a boolean for whether there was a match or not, but you can pass a third parameter - $matches, which will contain the matches according to the regular expression provided.

You don't look to be using a regular expressions - for what you are doing you probably want to look at strpos instead. https://www.php.net/strpos

Comment: `preg_match()` returns an integer. It returns either 1 or 0. False if wrong regex supplied. See the doc.